# calling members of class to another class

Tags: java

hii every one
I m using Applets
i ve three classes ie three applets
and I need some members(variables) of one class into another class

when i m trying to access variables from one class to another class by creating of object of
called class in to calling class then it doesnt give wright output
it access those variables but gives null or zero values

Comment: If you post some code so we can see what you're doing you'll have a better chance of getting a helpful response

Comment: @Hussain can you give us some code, from which class are you trying to access which class variables, are they public? are they private with getters/setters, are the two classes in the same package?share some details

Comment: Are we talking about 3 different, independently started applets? If one applet calls another class, which happens to be an applet too, it should be possible, but not if it was started independently.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this isn't possible.

Won't each applet be loaded by a different classloader?  Won't this mean that the class namespaces will be kept separate by the JVM?

If that is the case, you will either have 3 versions of each class in existence (with no sharing of state ...) or the classloader will fail because it cannot find the other 2 classes when loading the first of the applets.